# datepicker disable futures dates and display today date as default date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datapicker

I would like to display today's date in my datapicker and in the same time disable future dates. For the moment I can only do one option, I can just disable future dates or I can display today's date.

here is my code:

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                endDate: today,
            });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: try `endDate: '0d'` or `maxDate: '0d'`

Comment: its not working

Comment: dozens of jquery datepickers available. find which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy", 
        maxDate : new Date() 
 });

MaxDate helps you to limit the future dates